# Replace . with new lines in text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing names of people seperated by . how to replace the . with new lines so that each name is in new line with powershell

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, we will help you if you try yourself but we wont do the work for you

Answer (score 2):

If you have the latest version of PSCX (3.2.0) http://pscx.codeplex.com, we just added a new command to simplify this type of task a bit:

```
Edit-File -Path c:\path\to\file.txt -Pattern '\.' -Replacement "`r`n"
```

Or using positional params:

```
Edit-File c:\path\to\file.txt '\.' "`r`n"
```

This command also handles taking care that the file's original encoding is preserved.  Using `Out-File` will output using Unicode unless you override with the -Encoding parameter which of course requires that you know the file's encoding in the first place.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple replace...

```
(gc c:\path\to\file.txt) -replace "\.","`n" | out-file c:\path\to\newfile.txt
```

Comment: You need to stop being bored and encouraging bad questions like this. :)

Comment: I don't do it very often, but this seriously took me about as much time to answer and just get the OP to move on as it would have for me to scold him.